# Error: "could not find a part of the path" on published code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting below error:
"could not find a part of the path"

This is happening only when I ran published web API. But the same code is working fine.
Below is that code:

```
string fileName = string.Format(@"C:\\Reports\\AttendanceReport " + start.ToString("d") + " To " + end.ToString("d") + ".xlsx");
                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(fileName.ToString());
                excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
```

*file is created if I running code locally. But not working for published code.

Comment: Does the application pool have access (permissions) to the folder `C:\Reports`? Does the folder exist on the server?

Comment: I just provided rights to that folder with the steps give on site: 'https://support.pkware.com/display/SMAR/KB+-+Granting+folder+permissions+to+IIS+application+pools'

Folder is also present on that path, still having this issue...

Comment: First try with C:\\Reports\\AttendanceReport.xlsx If you get success then you know something is wrong with start and end variable that you have written.

Comment: Yeah! This is working now. I used below code-


 string fileName = string.Format(@"C:\Reports\AttendanceReport_" + 
                                                                                start.ToString("dd") + "_" + start.ToString("MMM") + "_to_" +
                                                                                end.ToString("dd") + "_" + end.ToString("MMM") +
                                                                                ".xlsx");
                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(fileName.ToString());
                excel.SaveAs(excelFile);